# Transcendental approximation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The equation $ h_c= \frac{b}{8 \pi f (1+ \mu)} \ln \left(\frac{eh_c}{r_o} \right)$ can be approximated as $h_c=\frac{b}{9.9f}$ under certain conditions.
$\mu=0.3,e=2.71,r_o=3$
How is the approximation  done and what are the assumptions made ?

Comment: Make a Taylor expansion  of $\ln$.

Comment: Please show some work

Comment: To add something. I don't know how the approximation was done and what assumptions were made, my crystal ball is on the fritz. I can only say as above, I guess it is a sort of Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's write this as $$ \dfrac{h}{\ln h} = x $$
where $h = e h_c/r_0$ and $x = \dfrac{eb}{8 \pi r_0 (1+\mu) f}$.
The solution of this is $h = - x W(-1/x)$ where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function.  In this case I think you want the $-1$ branch, which gives a real value
when $-1/e < -1/x < 0$ (this is the mathematical $e = \exp(1)$: I don't know if yours is supposed to be that, or if it really is $2.71$).
As $x \to + \infty$, $h \to +\infty$ as well.  But note that $h/x = \ln h \to \infty$, so your approximation could only possibly be good for a very restricted range of $x$.   Essentially you're treating $\ln h$ as constant (about $3.3$), 
so this is only good if $h \approx \exp(3.3) \approx 27$.